# virtual host setup points to other directory(one directory down)

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I have setup a "Named based virtual host" as follow.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
 ServerName www.exmaple.com

 # Other directives here
 <Directory /var/www/html/example>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But, when I visit to example.com, it is not pointing to `/var/www/html/example` folder.

Actually it takes me to the index.html of `/var/www/html`

---

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Do you know why and where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Are you sure that you have your config file symlinked in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`? If not, you need to do so and restart the apache for the config to be accessible to apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ServerName` is set to `www.exmaple.com` which is different from `example.com`. For `example.com` your Apache seems to use the default VirtualHost configuration.

Either change your `ServerName`, add `example.com` as an `ServerAlias` or visit `www.exmaple.com` (note the spelling!) - you may have to add an entry to `/etc/hosts` or your DNS server for the latter one.

Comment: Yes, this really is educational. For some reason, I thought 
ServerName `example.com` and
ServerName `www.example.com` is the same. But, it does NOT.

As a bonus point, it also clarify me that why ServerAlias is required.

thank you